# how can I check my user is already logged in, and go to specific view controller using NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize User_Name,Password,Login_Label,Register_Label;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];


NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (![defaults boolForKey:@"Registered"])
{

    NSLog(@"No User registered");


    // Login_Label.hidden = YES;



}else
{

    NSLog(@"User Registered");

    //Register_Label.hidden = YES;

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoggedInPage" sender:self];

}



// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}



- (IBAction)LogIn_Button:(id)sender {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if ([User_Name.text isEqualToString: [defaults objectForKey:@"userName"] ] && [Password.text isEqualToString: [defaults objectForKey:@"password"]])

{

    User_Name.text = nil;

    Password.text = nil;

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoggedInPage" sender:NULL];


}else
{

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"OOPS" message:@"Username or Password is in correct" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


    UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action)

                             {

                                 //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];

                             }];

    [alert addAction:action];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:Nil];

}


}


- (IBAction)Register:(id)sender {


if ([User_Name.text isEqualToString:@""] || [Password.text isEqualToString:@""])
{

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"OOPS" message:@"You must complete all fields" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action)

                             {

                                 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];

                             }];

    [alert addAction:action];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:Nil];

} else
{


    //[self NewRegisterUser];


}


[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"RegisterationPage" sender:self];

}



-(void) NewRegisterUser{

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


[defaults setObject:User_Name.text forKey:@"userName"];


[defaults setObject:Password.text forKey:@"password"];


[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"Registered"];


[defaults synchronize];


UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"You have registerd a new user" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action)

                         {

                             [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];

                             [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoggedInPage" sender:self];



                         }];

[alert addAction:action];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:Nil];


//[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoggedInPage" sender:self];


}



@end
```

Comment: what the issue u faced

Comment: What's wrong with your code? What is working? What is not working?

Comment: why you hide this `//[self NewRegisterUser];`

Comment: sometimes my users don't "log out", and just close the app. When they do this, the session doesn't expire; so when they restart the app and try and log in by typing in their username and password, they can't because they are already logged in.

If a session is still valid, how would I go about writing a line of code that checks the session upon loading the login view, that basically states, "If user is already logged in, go to [Name of ViewController Here]"

Comment: Thats not my problem....how can i stay on the viewcontroller if it they not logged out

Comment: how did you detect user logged out, show that code

Comment: first you have to store user login data in keychain not userdefaults ,  second check the existence of that data inside AppDelagate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and change the rootVC according to availability of session ,  if the user logged out clear the data and change the root again

Comment: @Sh_Khan - see this point `sometimes my users don't "log out", and just close the app. When they do this, the session doesn't expire; so when they restart the app and try and log in by typing in their username and password`

Comment: @Anbu.karthik its is in another viewcontroller

Comment: @Anbu.karthik the session is either a token or user data so he has to keep track of them

Comment: how will you identify user logged out, show that code of logged out action

Comment: All I want is I just want to show the loggedin page....if the user didnot logged out

Comment: - (IBAction)LogOut:(id)sender {
    //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MovetoLogin" sender:self];
}
@end

Comment: it seems that you don't clear the data or set a bool value indicates user logged out , also what do you mean by session in the context of your app

Comment: Nsuserdefault data that user entered

Comment: loggedout action you are nothing to change the userdefault activity, your ? is not clear , we unable to understand your query

Comment: once i logged in with the correct password and username....and then if i closed the simulator and opened it it should be in logged in.....but it shows me again the login button to login with username and password...did you under stand now

Comment: it shows that because you have to change the rootVC after you check the stored credentials for the user in AppDelegate

Comment: How can i do that

Comment: @Sh_Khan - it also one option we can follow, but problem is user not used this method `//[self NewRegisterUser];`

Comment: how to keep a user login even if they close the app? i am using NSUserdefaults..and objective-c @Anbu.karthik

Comment: @Rathna - enable this `//[self NewRegisterUser];`  and check once its works or not

Comment: i enabled it....it is used to store the registered values....

Comment: once get registered it gets login.....but when i close the the simulator and run with out the user get logged out...its shows me again login page...not the home page

Comment: Okay, just confirm what is getting printed in Log?  "User Registered" or "No User Registered" ? if log is printing properly and still its not navigating, then its a transition issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each Vc a storyboard identifier and do this

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

 if ([defaults boolForKey:@"LoggedIn"]) 
 {    
     UIViewController*vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeID"];
     UINavigationController*nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
     self.window.rootViewController = nav

  }else
  {

     UIViewController*vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginID"];
     UINavigationController*nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
     self.window.rootViewController = nav
  }
```

Comment: still not working @sh_khan

Comment: Did you tried it in appdelegate

Comment: yes.... @Sh_Khan

Comment: see edit .......

Comment: thanks @sh_Khan your code works fine....

Answer (score 0):

In the app delegate
After checking userDefaults, if not registered instantiate the loginViewController and set it as rootViewController else instantiate whichever viewController you want to appear and set it as the rootViewController.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (![defaults boolForKey:@"Registered"]) 
 {

    NSLog(@"No User registered");

   // Instantiate the LoginViewController

    NSString * storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard"; 
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER_OF_YOUR_VIEWCONTROLLER"];

   // Set it as the rootViewController

    self.window.rootViewController = vc;


   }else
  {

    NSLog(@"User Registered");

    //Instantiate the viewController that you would like a user to be taken to


    NSString * storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard"; 
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER_OF_YOUR_VIEWCONTROLLER"];

   // Set it as the rootViewController

    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
```

}

This code should go to the `didFinishLaunching with options` function in the appDelegate

Comment: Got error in this code

Answer (score 0):

Try following code its in swift version if you want i will write in objective c . or else modify following code based on your needs. in my case i am using tabbarcontroller in dashboard.

```
         func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

                  UserTypeValidateCall()

                return true
            }


         //MARK:- Validating User Type
            func  UserTypeValidateCall()
            {
                guard let Usertype = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userName") else {
                    return
                }



                if(( Usertype) != nil)
                {

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let ContentViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "your vc name") as! SKTabBarViewController
                navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ContentViewController)
                self.window?.rootViewController = navController
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        }
else
{

      window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let ContentViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SKLogInViewController") as! SKLogInViewController
            navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ContentViewController)
            self.window?.rootViewController = navController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


    }
        }
```

Comment: can you please convert it @Ram